# How can I escape from this loop?

Tags: c#, loops, switch-statement

I am a beginner at coding - I just started a week ago. I am trying to develop a program where the user can either see all of the names in a list or add a name to a list. When the user prompts to see the names in the list, and then decides to take another action, they are stuck in an endless loop where they can only see the names again. I want them to be able to go back to the start and choose to either see the names or add a name.

I've tried reorganizing and looking things up, but I'm still at a loss.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<string> names = new List<string>();
        names.Add("Vasti");
        names.Add("Cameron");
        names.Add("Ezra");
        names.Add("Tilly");
        bool program = false;
        bool program2 = false;
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the names lost! If you wish to add 
        a name to the list, type 1. If you want to see current names in 
        the list, 
        type 2.");
        string userChoice = Console.ReadLine();
        do
        {
            switch (userChoice)
            {
                case "1":
                    Console.WriteLine("Add a name to the squad.");
                    string userAddName = Console.ReadLine();
                    names.Add(userAddName);
                    break;
                case "2":
                    Console.WriteLine("Here's the list:");
                    foreach (string name in names)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(name);
                     }

                    Console.WriteLine("Wanna do that again? Type yes or 
                    no.");
                    do
                        {
                    string userContinue = Console.ReadLine();

                        switch (userContinue)
                        {
                            case "yes":
                                program = true;
                                program2 = false;
                                break;
                            case "Yes":
                                program = true;
                                program2 = false;
                                break;
                            case "no":
                                program = false;
                                program2 = false;
                                break;
                            case "No":
                                program = false;
                                program2 = false;
                                break;
                            default:
                                Console.WriteLine("Please enter either  
                                yes or no");
                                userContinue = Console.ReadLine();
                                program2 = true;
                                break;
                        }

                    }
                    while (program2 == true);

                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Please type either 1 or 2 to 
                    select an option.");
                    break;
            }
        }
        while (program == true);
    }
}
```

I expect the user to return to the beginning prompt, but they are stuck in the same prompt over and over. There are no error messages.

Comment: There's a lot of problems with this code. 1. The loop-in-a-switch-statement-in-a-loop is a little too nested considering each part handles different functionality. I'd probably break things up into separate methods. For example, "AddName" and "ListSquad". 2. The variable names are a little ambiguous (what is `program`? your whole application is a program). 3. The only place "userChoice" gets updated is in the inner loop of list squad. 4. At the moment, after you add a name to the squad, that's it, you exit the main loop. 5. You should look at how to do case insensitive matches vs Yes/yes, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two major things to cover your difficulties.

First, the input hint should be in the loop so it can show when each loop begin.

Second, `do while` loop decide if the loop should continue at the end and in your design; it depends on what user input which should be directly utilized as while condition.

Therefore, your code could be simplified as

```
public static void Main()
{
    List<string> names = new List<string>() { "Vasti", "Cameron", "Ezra", "Tilly" };

    string userChoice = "";
    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine($@"Welcome to the names lost!{Environment.NewLine} If you wish to add a name to the list, type 1.{Environment.NewLine} If you want to see current names in the list, type 2.");
        userChoice = Console.ReadLine();

        switch (userChoice)
        {
            case "1":
                Console.WriteLine("Add a name to the squad.");
                string userAddName = Console.ReadLine();
                names.Add(userAddName);
                break;
            case "2":
                Console.WriteLine("Here's the list:");
                foreach (string name in names)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(name);
                }

                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Please type either 1 or 2 to select an option.");
                break;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(@"Wanna do that again? Type yes or no.");
        userChoice = Console.ReadLine();
    }
    while (userChoice.Equals("yes", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

    Console.WriteLine("Program finished");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the do{}while() loops to regular while(){} loops.Move  string userChoice =  Cosole.ReadLine(); inside of the top while loop or you will never ask for other options. .  . Also set the ((bool program=true; and bool program=true;)) at the beginning. Do{}while() loops do everything inside the {} first then check to see if the while statement is still true.